# I am using document class elsarticle. In a table I want to break lines in multiple lines while keeping it two col format

Tags: tables

Here what I am using

```
  \begin{table}[h]
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
        
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
        
        
        \hline
        Dataset&Number of Speakers& Total utterances&Emotions\\
        \hline
        Berline Emotional Speech Database&10(5M,5F)&535&Angry, Boredom, Disgust, Fear, Happy, Sadness, Neutral\\
        
        
        
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

And the output is
[image]

But I want this
[image]

please guide.

After Mico's answer, I am getting this. Just need to add separation between these three items without adding any extra col for serial number. Also How to increase the width of the first and last col? Actually I need to understand this whole line`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{3}{C{0.8}} C{1.6} @{}}` Here what I am guessing : 3 means first 3 col widths of 0.8 and last of 1.6? plz, guide.
regards
[image]

Comment: never use resizebox with tables. `c` columns are single line use `p{6cm}` or whatever width you need in each case.  if you use `array` package you can use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{6cm}`  to get centred entries

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I was using resize to fit the table on the page otherwise it's crossing the column, is there any other way for this?  Also after using p{} it's not looking arranged, by so many adjustments in length. I wish I cud paste the output here.

Comment: you have not provided a usable test file but see Mico's answer here. There is no way to get reasonable output of you scale tables to fit, you should use consistent font sizes in teh document not scale to an arbitrary size.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I am saying it's not looking similar to what I have pasted in my question. But thanks again :)

Comment: you have not provided code in your question that we can run, but your table there uses `c` column types which does not allow line breaking in cells. Other than that I do not understand your comment, sorry.

Comment: I have given the code sir. mentioned the document class also. I am sorry If that's not enough. Also how to add pictures in comments :( is there any way? or I need to add by adding the answer to my own question here. Then probably I can clearly state what I want. Also, I get it why not use `c` here. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remark*: I wrote this answer to address the OP's initial query. Some time after I posted this answer, the OP changed the query more or less completely. I'm afraid that, as a result, my answer has become pretty much unintelligible to future readers, since it continues to address a query which is now no longer there.

I'd like to suggest that you employ a `tabularx` environments, with four centered versions of the `X` column type, and set the overall width to `\columnwidth`.

Alternatively, you could let the table occupy the width of both columns by using a `table*` environment and setting the width of the `tabularx` environment equal to `\textwidth`.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h] % all columns have same width
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} *{4}{C{1}} @{}}
        \toprule
        Dataset & Number of speakers & Total utterances & Emotions\\
        \midrule
        Berlin Emotional Speech Database & 10 (5M,~5F) & 535 & Angry, Boredom, Disgust, Fear, Happy, Sadness, Neutral\\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table*}[h] % final column is twice as wide as first three
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{3}{C{0.8}} C{1.6} @{}}
    \toprule
    Dataset & Number of speakers & Total utterances & Emotions\\
    \midrule
    Berlin Emotional Speech Database & 10 (5M,~5F) & 535 & Angry, Boredom, Disgust, Fear, Happy, Sadness, Neutral\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address one of the OP's follow-up queries:

> I need to understand this whole line `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{3}{C{0.8}} C{1.6} @{}}`

Let's start with the definition of the `C` column type:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
```

Here, the `X` column type is defined by the `tabularx` package and `\Centering` is a macro defined by the `ragged2e` package. If one or more columns of type `X` are present, their width is calculated as a residual, i.e., after subtracting the widths of all other columns from the first argument of the `\tabularx` environment. For instance,

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} *{4}{C{1}} @{}}
```

means that the overall width (the first arg. of the `tabularx` environment) is equal to `\columnwidth`, while `*{4}{C{1}}` means "4 columns of type `C`, all equally wide". (The `@{}` particles serve to suppress whitespace padding at the edges of the table.) The argument of `C` is a *relative* width, where "relative" is in reference to the case of equal-width X-type columns. The main rule to follow here is that *sum* of the relative column widths (here: 1+1+1+1=4) *must* be equal to the *number* of X-type columns (here: 4).

We may now turn to the second `tabularx` environment:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{3}{C{0.8}} C{1.6} @{}}
```

Its overall width is `\textwidth` (which is more than twice as large as `\columnwidth`, and it consists of 4 columns overall. The first three are centered X-type columns with *relative* widths equal to 0.8, while the fourth is also a centered X-type column, with *relative* width of 1.6. Observe that 3*0.8+1.6 = 2.4+1.6 = 4 = number of X-type columns. In words: the usable width of the final column is twice that of the usable width of the first three columns." If you want to increase the relative widths of the first and last columns, you must also decrease the relative width of the second and third columns. E.g.,

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} C{0.9} C{0.7} C{0.7} C{1.7} @{}}
```

would be a syntactically correct specification.

Comment: Thanks a  ton I think this two col is the best solution, Let me see if the editor allow me to do so. Regards

Comment: After your answer, I am getting the picture in edit section. Just need to add separation between these three items without adding any extra col for serial number. Also How to increase the width of the first and last col? Actually I need to understand this whole line\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{3}{C{0.8}} C{1.6} @{}} Here what I am guessing : 3 means first 3 col widths of 0.8 and last of 1.6? plz, guide. regards

Comment: @KRISHNACHAUHAN - Please clarify what you mean by "add separation between three items". Which "items" are you referring to? Separately, are you looking to modify the `table`/`\columnwidth` version or the `table*`/`\textwidth` version?

Comment: @KRISHNACHAUHAN - Please also see the addendum I just posted, in which I attempt to explain (hopefully successfully...) what `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{3}{C{0.8}} C{1.6} @{}}` means.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. Now My query was by separation of items I meant the gap between three datasets information like I have given in the example. where I wrote I want this :) actually in same format.

Comment: Now I am getting a better understanding , But could you plz help me with How to left alig in this situation as L or l in place of C is not working. I want to paste my results here But I think its not possible in comments.

Comment: @KRISHNACHAUHAN - Sorry, but *no*. I wrote my answer to address a very different question from what you have now, and I don't have the energy to figure out everything you've changed in the meantime. If you have a substantially new question, you should post a new question.